# Could not find python Interpreter - Opencv cmake error

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and trying to install opencv 3.3.0. While I execute cmake to get the make files, it is not able to locate the Python interpreter, displaying the following message **(though the cmake proceeds)**

```
    -- Could NOT find PythonInterp: Found unsuitable version "2.7.6", 
       but required is at least "3.4" (found /usr/bin/python)
    -- Could NOT find PythonInterp: Found unsuitable version "2.7.6", 
       but required is at least "3.2" (found /usr/bin/python)
```

When I check **/usr/bin/** ,  I could see python libraries/binaries present there **(found in the image below)**

[image]

I could also see the following versions of python

```
 python             python2.7-config   python3.4          python3.4m-
 config  python3.5m-config  python3m-config    
 python2            python2-config     python3.4-config   python3.5          
 python3-config     python-config      
 python2.7          python3            python3.4m         python3.5m         
 python3m           python-mkdebian
```

How can I solve this? Due to this issue, I am not able to use **cv2** in my python script, as it throws the following error

```
    ImportError: No module named 'cv2'
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve this problem is using `Anaconda` or `Miniconda`. You can easily install `opencv` by `conda install -c conda-forge opencv`.

An alternative is linking `/usr/bin/python` to `/usr/bin/python3.4`. It is not recommended.